# DB2 issue with date selection, basically want the previous 12 months from current date

Tags: db2

Okay the following `where` clause works, except in January when the calculation is turning up an invalid date:

```
WHERE
(DATE((DIGITS(LNYYP2) || '-' || DIGITS(LNMMP2) || '-' || DIGITS(LNDDP2))) > 
((CURRENT DATE - DAY (CURRENT TIMESTAMP) DAYS)) - 13 MONTH) 
AND DIGITS(SHFP02.LNYYP2) || '-' || DIGITS(LNMMP2) <> 
YEAR (CURRENT TIMESTAMP) || '-' || MONTH (CURRENT TIMESTAMP)
```

Comment: That is not tsql, regardless of your labeling. DB2 perhaps? And help others help you. What is an example of an "invalid" date? Does an error occur? If so, POST IT.

Comment: could be an SSIS expression

Comment: use datediff function and < 13

Comment: As stated I don't normally support this application, had thought most likely to be MSSQL but hey who knows. Unable to access the software at the moment to replicate the error but from end user request "Error during execution of SQL. ERROR: java.sql SQL Exception [SQL0181] Value in date, time, or timestamp string not valid". If I could access could narrow this done to the actual line.

Comment: `DIGITS` only seems to exist in DB2. I'm changing the tags and the title.

Comment: Edit the question to add the datatype+length of all referenced columns, and add the Db2-version and operating-system where Db2-server runs. The DIGITS() function will return leading zeroes and the DATE() will throw SQL0181, so the SQL looks incorrect to me.

Comment: Do you have an actual date/timestamp field in that table?  Or as part of a calendar table?  The current way you're querying things is going to ignore any relevant indices.  Also, dates should be queried with an inclusive lower-bound (`>=`), not exclusive like you do here.... perhaps `LNDDP2` has a 0 in it on January 1st?

Comment: @mao - that wouldn't explain why it only errors out during January

Comment: Now not so sure they haven't changed the database on me, cut the SQL down to bare bones and it works fine, as soon as I add in a couple of fields it displays the error.

Comment: @clockwork-muse :  can you show any circumstance when `DATE((DIGITS(LNYYP2) || '-' || DIGITS(LNMMP2) || '-' || DIGITS(LNDDP2))` will not throw SQL0181?

Comment: @ScaryMinds - Actually, I have a sneaking suspicion `LNYYP2` may only be a two-digit field, which would prevent it from working (but it should work none of the time if that's the case, not "just in january")

Comment: @mao - sure: `SELECT DATE(DIGITS(LNYYP2) || '-' || DIGITS(LNMMP2) || '-' || DIGITS(LNDDP2)) FROM (VALUES(CAST(1917 AS NUMERIC(4, 0)), CAST(2 AS NUMERIC(2, 0)), CAST(1 AS NUMERIC(2, 0)))) AS T(LNYYP2, LNMMP2, LNDDP2)`

Comment: @clockwork-muse : accepted, but I'm betting that the datatype of the columns is not numeric(x,0) or decimal(x,0) in the DDL . If it is char, or int, or smallint then SQL181 will result.

Answer (score 1):

Potential issue:

For the second condition,

```
(DATE((DIGITS(LNYYP2) || '-' || DIGITS(LNMMP2) || '-' || DIGITS(LNDDP2))) > 
((CURRENT DATE - DAY (CURRENT TIMESTAMP) DAYS)) - 13 MONTH)
```

You're comparing two strings and not two dates or two sets of numbers. I'm not sure that's your issue because you don't give any sample data that gives right or wrong answers, but maybe it could be better written as:

```
and (lnyyp2, lnmmp2) not in (values(int(year(current date)), int(month(current date)))
```

Comment: ....but there's a `DATE(..)` function call, so the OP is comparing two dates?  And the exception listed is probably complaining about the conversion to the date in the first place.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, it looks like you are using a different DB than what I thought. This is an answer for how to solve this issue in SQL Server.

Original Anser:

I am not sure exactly what is going on in that where clause, but you can get 12 months ago with `DATEADD`. If you need to get the first of the month, you can build it with `DATEFROMPARTS`.

```
declare @today date;
declare @past date;

set @today = SYSDATETIME();
set @past =  dateadd(month, -12, @today)

select @today, @past, DATEFROMPARTS(YEAR(@past), MONTH(@PAST), 1)
```

Comment: Answer is correct if this were T-SQL, but code given by original poster shows it was DB2.